# How to use foreach to create variables from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create variables from a multidimensional array using foreach, but cannot access the nested arrays.

I tried using foreach again within my current foreach command, but I think something in the format of the array will not let me do this.

PHP:

```php
$response = curl_exec($cURL);

$result = json_decode($response, true);

$someArray = $result;
foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {;
}

curl_close($cURL);

print $value["registration"];
print $value["make"];
print $value["model"];
print $value["fuelType"];
print $value["primaryColour"];
```

This is exactly how I receive the array. I can create variables for registration, make, model, firstUsedDate, fuelType and primaryColour.

```php
array(
    [0] => array(
        [registration]  => DU11LVA
        [make]          => MINI
        [model]         => MINI(R57)
        [firstUsedDate] => 2011.03.05
        [fuelType]      => Diesel
        [primaryColour] => White

        [motTests]      => array(

            [0] => array(
                [completedDate]  => 2018.04.1116:00:30
                [testResult]     => PASSED
                [expiryDate]     => 2019.04.10
                [odometerValue]  => 45283
                [odometerUnit]   => mi
                [motTestNumber]  => 138359719457

                [rfrAndComments] => array(
                    [0] => array(
                        [text] => Nearside Front Road wheel with a slightly distorted bead rim INSIDE (4.2.A.1a) 
                        [type] => ADVISORY)))

            [1] => array(
                [completedDate]  => 2018.04.1110:22:54
                [testResult]     => FAILED
                [odometerValue]  => 45283
                [odometerUnit]   => mi
                [motTestNumber]  => 652014545840

                [rfrAndComments] => array(
                    [0] => array(
                        [text] => Nearside Front Road wheel with a slightly distorted bead rim INSIDE (4.2.A.1a) 
                        [type] => ADVISORY)
                    [1] => array(
                        [text] => Nearside Front Shock absorber has a serious fluid leak (2.7.3) 
                        [type] => FAIL)))

            [2] => array(
                [completedDate]  => 2017.04.0610:27:08
                [testResult]     => PASSED
                [expiryDate]     => 2018.04.08
                [odometerValue]  => 37579
                [odometerUnit]   => mi
                [motTestNumber]  => 605834707501

                [rfrAndComments] => array())
```

I'm trying to get the expiryDate and odometerValue.

Comment: ***I am trying to get the expiryDate and odometerValue*** is this your question?

Comment: That is the **wierdest** way of using a foreach to access an array I have ever seen

Comment: You have to learn how to use foreach https://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: if you are looking to target any element in specific, e.g. `expiryDate` or `odometerValue`, just look at the array structure using `print_r()` or `var_dump()` and follow the _path_ to your target, e.g. `echo $someArray[0]['motTests'][0]['expiryDate'];` or `echo $someArray[0]['motTests'][0]['odometerValue'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array that contains other arrays, so keeping it simple and just using foreach loops, when ever you want something from an inner array you start another foreach loop to process it.

Also the code that is making use of the loop processing should live inside the foreach and not be coded after it.

```
$response = curl_exec($cURL);

$result = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($cURL);

foreach ($result as $value) {    

    print $value["registration"];
    print $value["make"];
    print $value["model"];
    print $value["fuelType"];
    print $value["primaryColour"];

    foreach ($value['motTests'] as $mot) {
        print $mot['expiryDate'];
        print $mot['odometerValue'];
    }
}
```